# How to change existing elements in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created some circles using `selectAll().enter().append()`...etc. I would like to edit this by either transitioning some elements elsewhere or changing colors of them. How do I do this?

I tried using the following, but it doesn't work:

```
circle.transition().style("fill", "blue");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following to fill all circle with `blue` color :

`d3.selectAll('circle').style("fill", "blue");`

Comment: It doesn't do anything. You check my fiddle here if it's of any use: http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/

Comment: When I have created all the circles I would like to change the colors of each section of the circles. Like I want t(15;17) to stay red, inv(16)/t(16;16) to turn blue, t(8;21) to turn yellow etc etc.

Comment: I would also like to transition all the circles on the graph instead of them just appearing all of a sudden. But I presume I'd know how to do that when I know how to change existing circles

Comment: @Vanquiza Works fine for me if I just copy and paste the suggested code into your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/1/

Comment: Okay I see, I must've written something wrong myself, although it was unclear for me how to update this earlier, so thank you. Supposed I'd want to re-arrange my circles Y position with a new dataset, by transitioning them to their new destinations. How would perform this task? I've tried using `attr.("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))} )` to update my Y-coordinates by adding `data(graphData[i], function(d){return d;})` with my new data, but this does not work.